# R BCA library not loading or crashing R session

Tags: r

Every time I try to load BCA library in R with the command

```
library(BCA)
```

R (and Rstudio) crashes. I have tried to load it from packages, selecting it, but doing this R behaves like the library is not loaded, returning the error that the library is not loaded.

Comment: When you install the library, does it give any errors? Have you tried loading it through R/Rgui, circumventing RStudio? Please give more information (where you're installing the package from, R version, OS type and version...).

Comment: The same for Rgui, and i get the same problem, it crashes. When i installed it didnt give any errors. I using MacOS High Sierra with R 3.4.3 and RStudio 1.1.423

Comment: So to be clear, you load the package, it gives error and then crashes? Can you post a screenshot of the crash?